# Looking for Win CE DiskPrep PowerToy

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, bootable

I'm trying to find Windows CE DiskPrep PowerToy.
Old link was on Microsoft archive gallery, but now it's retired.
Also Mr. ctacke (https://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke) published it in his blog, but it seems its retired too.
Any hint for a new download link? 
I need to create a bootable CF for Windows CE.
Thanks
MDLT

Answer (score 2):

Update to this:

The DiskPrep utility is now part of the “Power Suite for Windows Embedded Compact Platforms”, available for download via the following URL:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47266